# Coderush search for specific issues

Tags: c#, .net, performance, coderush

how i can in coderush see only the issues related to a specific problem. For example i want to iterate over the clases that is not calling dispose().

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [CodeRush Code Issues tool window](http://www.skorkin.com/2011/06/code-issues-tool-window/) that shows a summary of code issues found inside the source code within an entire solution. It is intended to help you overview, analyze and navigate between code issues. The window has a Filter that allows you to specify code issue filtering options for the entire list. You can choose any issues you would like to see there, so you will see only the list of specific issues.